# How to select where condition equal null.

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, select

SQL statement:

```
select * FROM Message
 WHERE senderId = 126 and receiverId = 125
   and dateReceived is null
```

HQL statement:

```
 FROM Message
WHERE senderId = :senderId and receiverId = :receiverId
 and dateReceived is null
```

I got error. so how to write HQL to get result same to above sql statement?

Comment: What error do you get? The trace should give you the answer.

Comment: Please provide more context. Maybe the error would help?

Answer (score 3):

Try  using IS EMPTY should work.

Answer (score 2):

Are senderId and receiverId foreign keys?
if yes, then suppose senderId is a column of Sender table and receiverId is a column of Receiver table try this one:

```
select msg FROM Message msg
 WHERE msg.Sender.senderId = 126 and msg.Receiver.receiverId = 125
   and msg.dateReceived is null
```

OR

```
Select msg FROM Message msg
WHERE msg.senderId = :senderId and msg.receiverId = :receiverId
 and msg.dateReceived is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by

HQL Query :
FROM Message
WHERE senderId = :senderId and receiverId = :receiverId
and dateReceived = null